# Is it possible to have a Union within a Union?

Tags: mysql, union

I have three tables that I create in separate reports that involve UNIONS. I was wondering if it would be possible to create one large report that itself UNIONed the separate UNIONs I use in other reports.

It looks something like this right now:

```
SELECT
z.name,
z.social

FROM
(SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT
 accta.name,
 accta.social
 FROM accta
 WHERE accta.name <> 'Bob'
 GROUP BY name

UNION

SELECT
 acctb.name,
 acctb.social
 FROM acctb
 GROUP BY name

UNION

SELECT
 acctc.name,
 acctc.social
 FROM acctc
 GROUP BY name) a

UNION

(SELECT
 accta.name,
 accta.social
 FROM accta
 GROUP BY name

UNION

SELECT
 acctb.name,
 acctb.social
 FROM acctb
 WHERE acctb.name <> 'Steve'
 GROUP BY name

UNION

SELECT
 acctc.name,
 acctc.social
 FROM acctc
 GROUP BY name) b

) z

GROUP BY z.name
```

So basically Im unioning three tables to create table a then attempting to union that with another table made of unions.

Is such a thing even possible?  I keep getting errors.

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: It always give me an error on the first UNION after table a

Comment: Nevermind,, I figured it out, you need the SELECT * statement in front of table b as well; otherwise you aren't selecting any data for the tables to UNION on

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you want to add hierarchy to your unions, just use the parentheses:

```
SELECT columnName FROM tableName 
UNION (SELECT columnName FROM anotherTableName UNION SELECT columnName FROM thirdTableName) 
ORDER BY columnName;
```

Answer (score 0):

There was simply an error in syntax, I need to add the SELECT * statement in front of table b. As the code is in my example, nothing is being selected in table b so the tables aren't unioning on anything.